# Finding realistic peak data transfer rate across a cluster

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a big cluster from which I'm transferring data to another source. The other source has some scaling limits and we need to provide a realistic peak data transfer rate.

My cluster has 12000 nodes and the probability that a node is transferring data at any given instant is: 0.02

Each node can transfer data at 100 MB/s.

From this data can I find a more realistic peak load? (worst case is 1200 * 100 which will be too unrealistic based on probability)

Comment: If each node actually transfers data at 100MB/s (versus "can transfer") and all that bandwidth is directed at "another source" (which actually sounds like a sink), then the expected cumulative rate is 1200*.02*100MB/s = 2400MB/s (approximately 2.3GB/s). However a "peak load" depends on what you mean by "peak". While very unlikely the absolute peak would be 1200*100. So for example do you mean the peak you expect to see during the course of an hour, day, etc? Do you have probability density function associated with a node either transferring or not? Does data get dropped if sink is overloaded?

Comment: @Χpẘ Thanks! If the sink is overloaded it might cause an outage so I want to make sure that sink is never overloaded. Sink currently can not be provisioned for peak (12000*100) so we want to provision sink for more realistic load. I don't have a probability density function but I know that a node transfers 1GB data file every 10 minutes. Assuming 100 MBPs it gives 10 seconds for transferring 1GB data. Thus ~.02 probability that the data is being transferred at an instant

Comment: I'm guessing the nodes aren't deliberately synchronized (staggered) WRT file transfer. What happens if the cluster is restarted? Do the nodes tend to all send data in the same 10 second window right after the reboot? The larger point is that the "probability" may not be random, and that ~.02 is more like the duty cycle. If nodes' transfer could be staggered in .5 sec increments and there's no systematic drift of the 10 minute intervals then determining the peak is straightforward. Also  what happens if there is network congestion or other delays forcing the nodes to "unstagger"?

Comment: @Χpẘ During cluster restart, hosts are activated in a staggered manner. Also, 1 GB is the average data generated over 10 mins and some nodes might generate this in 8, some might take 11 mins, so it is staggered there as well. But it is possible that this data is not completely staggered hence looking for a reasonable peak. I was looking at Poisson distribution, but not sure if that would give a correct result